# JSX Dictionary problem with onChange in Edit Form

Tags: javascript, dictionary, hashmap

I have a form with an input field where the User enters whatever name. I need to check if this name already exists, but in the edit field it needs to ignore its original name as a duplicate.

I'm looking for help with the js method

```
const isUnique = input => {
  const dictionary = {};
  // dictionary[iGetExistingNames] = 1
  // so now the dictionary = {'a':1, 'b':1, 'c':1}

  // how do I add new inputs as a key and set value to +1 and when backspace reduce the count?

  // return bool 
}
```

Comment: Try out some code, then post a question with something more specific. In this way it looks that the only thing you did is to create an empty object

Answer (score 0):

You will need to check if your `dictionary` contains the input. If not, then add it otherwise it is a duplicate and increment the count.

```
// Say you have a dictionary with the key named john
const dictionary = {'john': 1}

// Check for the key using
dictionary['john']  // This should return 1.

// Add new keys using
dictionary[input] = 0;
```

Comment: so I'm not able to increment the way I thought I'd be able to
dictionary[name]++

Comment: Are you getting an error? What happens when you do ```dictionary[name]++```? In the above example, ```dictionary['john']++``` increments the count to 2.

Comment: He does not because in his code at every call of the func, he inits back the dictionary to an empty object